# disable XQuartz and revert to mavericks's default x server

Tags: osx-mavericks, x11, mplayer, xquartz

I have installed XQuartz 2.7.5 on Mavericks. After that videos I play with mplayer seems to load on a separate window, all white stuck with only the audio playing. I have disabled Xquartz by disabling /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist and /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist with launchctl.

Iwould like to know how to display the videos as it was playing before. I installed mplayer via brew. Is there a way to direct $DISPLAY to the default x server? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't disable /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist.  That will prevent XQuartz.app from launching.

Disabling /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist (and relogging) will result in the DISPLAY environment variable not being set and thus automatic launching of XQuartz.app when you run X11 applications, but you can still launch XQuartz.app directly.

There is no default X server.  X11 was removed from OS X in Mountain Lion.  X11.app in earlier versions of OS X was just XQuartz.app with different name.